# How to put an Array Value to echo individually

Tags: php, arrays

I want to echo the array on a different location but I cannot make it to work.

i can echo the array if I do these

```
foreach($domain as $value) {
   echo $value;
}
```

bot cannot echo it individually

```
foreach($domain as $value) {
  $domainame[] = $value; 
}

echo '<p> your first domain' .$domainname[0];
echo '<p> your last domain' .$domainname[5];
```

Comment: Are you sure there are 6 domain names?

Comment: Do you get an error? What's the result? Show us the content of `$domain`.

Comment: What's the point of the loop? `$domainname` is just a copy of `$domain`.

Comment: lol. `$domainame !==$domainname `.extra `n` is there. So it's basically a TYPO mistake. Check here:- https://eval.in/892808

Comment: $domain value will be coming from a textarea

Comment: @JeVic  check the answer below

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you have to do like this

```
$i = 0;

foreach($domain as $value){

$domainame[$i] = $value;
$i++;

}
```

and now you can do this

```
echo '<p> your first domain' .$domainname[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this:

```
var_export($array);
var_dump($array);
print_r($array);
```

For each of the above it's useful to first ( when outputting to html )

```
echo "<pre>";
```

A pre tag to preserve the white space.  Each one of these have some uniqueness to them.  While I cant cover them all.

- `var_export` - outputs valid PHP comparable text, so you can paste an array right into your code after outputting it with this.  It has a second argument `$string = var_export($array,true)` that will return it as a string
- `var_dump` - tells you the type of variable, such as `int`, `array` etc..
- `print_r` - is more "human" readable.

If you want to get really wild you can use, `array_map` instead of a loop:

```
 array_map(function($item){
     echo $item;
 }, $array);
```

At first one would think you could simply do

```
 array_map('echo', $array);
```

But, alas `echo` is not a real function, it's a language construct, so you have to wrap it in a closure.  Compare this to `var_dump`

```
array_map('var_dump', $array )
```

Works just fine.

And last but not least you could always do

```
 echo json_encode($array);
```

But that probably won't be to readable.

I am sure there are some I am forgetting.

**UPDATE**

I thought you just wanted to generally output it.  Anyway, you can use `array_map`

```
     array_map(function($item){
          echo "<p> your first domain{$domainame[0]}</p>";  //dont forget the typo
     }, $array);
```

I think  @Alive to Die, got it with the typo.  But, if you output it using any of the above you would see it was empty.

One thing I should mention, as you should have gotten a warning for this, when developing you should have error reporting turned on ether globally in the `php.ini` or at least in the file your working on

```
   <?php
     error_reporting(-1);  //error level E_ALL
     ini_set('display_errors', 1);  //output errors
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply write:

```
echo '<p> your first domain' .$domain[0];
echo '<p> your last domain' .$domain[5];
```

no point of looping at all!

Comment: I am not a down-voter. It's correct .+1 from my side atleast